# Why Chinese character changes to different format while redirecting to another JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I'm trying to insert a chinese character into the DB, but while redirecting from one jsp to another jsp the value changes from  油墨 to æ²¹å¢¨ and the changed value is inserted to DB.
For this I used the below tag.

```
 <%@ page language="java"  contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
 pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

Comment: This seems to be a charset issue to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chinese character encoding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211612/chinese-character-encoding)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you support `UTF-8` in your database's text fields, if so, you need to use UTF-8 encoding in all you app.

If you're using `Tomcat` server, you can follow the  [UTF-8 everywhere HOWTO](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q8) from Tomcat FAQ.

If you use JBoss try this:

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.USE_BODY_ENCODING_FOR_QUERY_STRING" value="true"/>
</system-properties>
```

Check also [this post](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/190925?start=0&tstart=0) if you still having troubles...

Comment: Before inserting the data into the DB , the value is changed(different font and format). If i insert manually it takes as I give. so there is no problem in DB side. while redirecting the JSP only it happens..Thats where I'm facing problem.

Comment: Which server are you using??